# Failing scripts in groovy using Grab

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

The following groovy scripts fail using command line

```
@Grab("org.apache.poi:poi:3.9")
println "test"
```

Error:

```
unexpected token: println @ line 2, column 1.
  println "test"
  ^
1 error
```

Removing the `Grab`, it works!
Anything I missed?

```
$>groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.1.7 JVM: 1.7.0_25 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Comment: `@Grab` annotation only applies to `import` statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Annotations can only be applied to certain targets.  See [SO: Why can't I do a method call after a @Grab declaration in a Groovy script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727355/why-cant-i-do-a-method-call-after-a-grab-declaration-in-a-groovy-script#5727638)

```
@Grab("org.apache.poi:poi:3.9")
dummy = null
println "test"
```

Alternatively you can use grab as a method call:

```
import static groovy.grape.Grape.grab
grab(group: "org.apache.poi", module: "poi", version: "3.9")
println "test"
```

For more information refer to [Groovy Language Documentation > Dependency management with Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html).

Answer (score 0):

## File 'Grabber.groovy'

```
package org.taste

import groovy.grape.Grape

//List<List[]> artifacts => [[<group>,<module>,<version>,[<Maven-URL>]],..]
static def grab (List<List[]> artifacts) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = new groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader()
    def eal = Grape.getEnableAutoDownload()
    artifacts.each { artifact -> {
            Map param = [
                classLoader: classLoader, 
                group : artifact.get(0),
                module : artifact.get(1),
                version : artifact.get(2),
                classifier : (artifact.size() < 4) ? null : artifact.get(3)
            ]
            println param
            Grape.grab(param) 
        }
    }
    Grape.setEnableAutoDownload(eal)
}
```

## Usage :

```
package org.taste
import org.taste.Grabber

Grabber.grab([
    [ "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder", "http-builder", '0.7.1'],
    [ "org.postgresql", "postgresql", '42.3.1', null ],
    [ "com.oracle.database.jdbc", "ojdbc8", '12.2.0.1', null]
])
```